# executing multiple instance of an executable and changing their output file name in cmd line

Tags: windows, cmd

I have an executable that need to be spawned in different processes using command line in windows. I want to change the name "concatenate date and process number" output file which is a text file.

The instances are computationally intensive so they take a long time....can we make a script wait in each process and rename the output file in that process.

Here is what I did , but it doesn't seem to work

```
@ECHO OFF
set progPath=%cd%
cd %progPath%

set nprs=3

for /l %%x in (1, 1, %nprs%) do ( start execMCS.exe ren output.txt  output%nprs%.txt );
```

Comment: I don't completely understand and I might misunderstand but perhaps you can create a second cmd file that executes execMCS then it does the rename. Then the first cmd file executes the second one for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to achieve the following:

```cmd
@echo off
cd /D "D:\working_directory"
set "nprs=3"
for /L %%x in (1,1,%nprs%) do (
    start "" cmd /C "execMCS.exe" ^& ren "output.txt" "output%%x.txt"
)
```

`start` starts an application, so you cannot state multiple ones, neither can you state internal commands of `cmd`. You can however start a new `cmd` instance and execute both an application and an internal command (`ren`) therein, concatenated by the `cmd`-internal `&` operator.

You may want to specify the absolute path to the executable file rather than its name only.

It does not make sense to change to the directory stored in variable `%CD%`, because this is already the current working directory. That is why I changed the `cd` command line.